# How to set a dynamic property for MockObject instance that has been initialed already in phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit, slim

I'm working with Slim framework (ver3.1) and unit test with phpunit (ver7.3). I'm facing with a problem that when I try to set a dynamic property to a initialed mock object, then I can't retrieve it again.

```
$mockedUser = $this->getMockBuilder(User::class)
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();
$mockedUser->isRoot = true;
echo $mockedUser->isRoot ? 'Root' : 'Not root';
```

The above code should print out 'Root' as a result. However, it prints 'Not root' instead.
I did try to mock the __set and __get method, but they did not work either.

Please help me out!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please show us the class `User`.

Comment: It's just a simple class ```class User {}```

Comment: Then you don't need to mock this class.

Comment: While @odan is right in that you don't have to mock the User object in this case, it should still work. Did you edit the `__get` or `__set` functions manually?